# Logical operator OR to get value

Tags: java, logical-operators

I have final value for example „**3221120076**“ (data type long). I have a few enums like

```
MONDAY(0x0002)
TUESDAY(0x0004)
WEDNESDAY(0x0008)
THURSDAY(0x0010)
FRIDAY(0x0020)
SATURDAY(0x0040)
SUNDAY(0x0080)
```

How could I check, how to get the final long value combining values of this enums?

Comment: Well how did you get a value of 3221120076 to start with? What's that meant to represent?

Comment: Yes, I already thought that, but Im working with external data, so that is probably problem. @JonSkeet

Comment: Well yes, but it's not a problem we can help you with. We could make up *possible* ways of combining values, but there'd be no guarantee that it's the same meaning that you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume that you can only use each value once.
if that's the case you would want to turn the number in binairy.

the algorithim to do that is:
with example : 11

11 % 2 == 1 ? yes tmp = 1; and divide 11-1 by 2

5 % 2 == 1? yes tmp = 11; same as above;

2 % 2 == 1? no tmp = 110; divide 2 by 2;

1 % 2 == 1? yes tmp = 1101;

now reverse tmp and you get 11 in binairy is 1011